# Python script compiled to C binary and execute in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, binary, executable

I would like to complie my python script with a few variables to binary file and execute it in Docker container.
To achive that I am using Cython and gcc compiler.

I have a problem with run binary file. I get error in container log:
`/bin/sh: 1: /app/script: Exec format error`

Below dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-dev \
                          gcc \
                          libc-dev \
                          libffi-dev

RUN apt-get install -y bash &&\
    pip install --upgrade pip &&\
    pip3 install cython


RUN cython /app/script.pyx --embed
RUN gcc -Os -I/app/env/include/python3.7m -L/app/env/include/python3.7m -o script script.c -c -lpython3.7m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl

ENV arg1=''
ENV arg2=''
ENV arg3=''
ENV arg4=''

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/app/script"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-l", "-c", "/app/script"]
```

In folder /app/env I have Conda enviroment.

Is there anyone who has similar problem to my?
Thank you for the answers and sugestions

Comment: Doesn't the [`gcc -c` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Overall-Options.html) compile the `.c` source file to a `.o` object file, not an executable?  You should probably get a bunch of warnings that the `-l` options are ignored.  Does removing the `-c` option help?  (Does running this same workflow, with the same command, work outside of Docker?)

Comment: @DavidMaze I think gcc complie file to executable. When I invoke (without flag `-c`) from linux console `gcc -Os -I /home/PycharmProjects/PythonToC/env/include/python3.7m -o script script.c -lpython3.7m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl`, I can run from console `./script` and it working fine.

Comment: @DavidMaze When I compling dokerfile I don't have any warning. But if I change command to `RUN gcc -Os -I/app/env/include/python3.7m -L/app/env/include/python3.7m -o script script.c -lpython3.7m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl` (without flag `-c`), I get error during compliation `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.7m
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`.

Comment: @DavidMaze I complie docerfile with `RUN gcc -Os -I/app/env/include/python3.7m -L/app/env/include/python3.7m -o script script.c -c -lpython3.7m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl` and modify entrypoint to `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/app/script"]` and I get in container log `/app/script: 1: Syntax error: ")" unexpected`

Comment: Based on above error I have changed entrypoint command in dockerfile to `ENTRYPOINT ["./app/script"]` and get following message in docker log:
`standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error`.

Comment: In next step I have created shell script with two lines `#!/bin/bash
./script` and invoke in dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/app/invoke"]` and I get message in docker log `/app/invoke: line 2: ./script: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`.

Comment: With the `gcc -c` option you have an unlinked object file, not an executable.  (If you run `gcc` without `-c`, the binary it produces should already be executable; you should not need to `chmod +x` it.)  I do note that you're starting `FROM python:3.10` but then explicitly trying to link in Python 3.7 libraries, that won't be in this image.

Comment: @DavidMaze, you are right. I have changed image from `python:3.10` to `python:3.7`, also remove flag `-c` and everything looks good. I have copied from container compiled script to host and it works. However in container is not working. Do you know how `entrypoint` command should look like for executable files?

Comment: It should be absent, and your `CMD` should name the binary to run; `CMD ["/app/script"]`.

Comment: I have checked `CMD ["/app/script"]` and in docker logs I have `No logs available`, container is always restaring.
In main function in python script I put line with `LOGGER.info("Main function")`, so I expect that docker log should view this comment.

Comment: I have checked `CMD ["script"]` and in docker logs I have `Script started, output log file is 'typescript'.
# 
Script done.` and typescript contains `Script started on 2022-01-06 19:45:05+00:00 [<not executed on terminal>]
# 
Script done on 2022-01-06 19:45:05+00:00 [COMMAND_EXIT_CODE="0"]`.

Comment: I have also checked command `CMD ["./script"]`, similar to which I use to lunch script in host terminal `./script`.
The outputs in docke logs is `No logs available`.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my solution.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:alpine3.7

RUN apk update && \
    apk add python3-dev libc-dev libffi-dev gcc &&\
    pip install --upgrade pip

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
WORKDIR /home/user

COPY --chown=user:user requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY --chown=user:user script.pyx script.pyx
COPY --chown=user:user invoke invoke
COPY --chown=user:user setup.py setup.py

ENV PATH="/home/user/.local/bin:${PATH}"

RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt

RUN cython script.pyx --embed &&\ 
    gcc -Os -I /usr/local/include/python3.7m -o script script.c -lpython3.7m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl &&\
    rm -f script.pyx &&\
    rm -f script.c &&\
    rm -f requirements.txt

ENV arg1=''
ENV arg2=''
ENV arg3=''
ENV arg4='''

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "invoke"]
```

**Shell script "invoke"**

```
#!/bin/bash
./script
```

Thanks to [@David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze?tab=profile) for suggestions.